# Create derived class from base class object

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have base class which is generic parser of some data, and I have multiple derived classes which provide specific access interface to data contained in parser. I can determine the type of derived class only after all data is parsed, since it depends on the hierarchy (there is the tree of base classes, which needs to be fully populated to determine derived class for each base).

What is the best way to create derived class from base class, avoiding unnecessary copying of the data? As of now, I'm creating derived using copy constructor of base (as below):

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  Derived(const Base &base)
  : Base(base)
  {
  }
};
```

, but this requires copying all the base data which is no necessary - I want base class to become derived without copying and deleting it if possible.

EDIT:

Base parser parses data file and stores data generically as map >, while derived classes provide specific access interface depending on hte actual data type stored. Derived classes may change and more can be added.

Comment: Maybe you can give `Base` a move constructor and make `Derived` also constructible from `Base&&`.

Comment: You need to *move* content from base to derived?

Comment: Sounds to me like `Base` and `Derived` violate the [Principle of Single Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Do you own the data format? If you do then I think you need to redesign this:  "I can determine the type of derived class only after all data is parsed" is the root cause of your problem. Certainly in the XML world you'd have something like a data type attribute before the actual data body.

Comment: Why is the parsing function part of the base class? It sounds like the parser should be a separate function, acting basically as a factory for the various classes.

Comment: @aschepler - yes, essentially move constructor would work perfectly, but my understanding is it is only in C++11, correct? Can I do this using C++03

Comment: You can usually get results similar to move semantics in C++03 by implementing and using `swap` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said that you must first parse all the data, and the question seems to suggest to me that you use `Base` to do the parsing.  (Note, subsequent OP edit has confirmed this to be the case.)

Then once the parsing is complete, you construct a `Derived` from the `Base` based on the data that was parsed.  This suggests to me that `Derived` is not just a parser, but some kind of container for the parsed data, as well as an actor on that parsed data. (Also confirmed.)

Having one class which both parses data and also contains parsed data and acts upon it is a violation of the [Principle of Single Resposibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Principles were meant to be broken, but I think that violating it in this case is causing you problems.

My suggestion is to break up your hierarchy.

- One class is the parser, and doesn't hold any data on it's own (except possibly for parsing state)
- One class holds raw, parsed data, with no management or actor methods.  Perhaps as simple as a `std::map`.
- One class is the actor, which does things with the data.  This would actually be a class hierarchy, with a different class for different types of parsed data.

The workflow would be something like this:

1. Instantiate the parser.
2. The parser instantiates a holder for the raw data, and parses the data.
3. The parser constructs the actor class based on the data that was parsed, passing it a `shared_ptr` to the raw data container.
4. The parser terminates, returning a pointer to the actor class, which by now owns the raw parsed data.

Comment: Please see edit - parser parses and stores data generically, derived provides access interface to data stored (converting from variants to suitable types)

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: But `Derived` is derived from `Base` -- meaning `Derived` **IS-A** parser.  Whether that was your intention or not.

Comment: Ok, perhaps storing the pointer to GenericParser in all interface classes instead of deriving them from parser would be a better design? I would like to avoid going into specifics about the contents of parser in interface classes - I would like access it as a whole...

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the derived class with its own constructor, and parse only the data you need to determine it. Passing a pointer is a good idea aswell, because it doesn't involve memory allocation.